# org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, junit

I am using spring boot and I have a RestController with method

```
addBook(@Validated @RequestBody BookDto bookDto)
```

BookDto has a field annotated with write only

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
@NotNull(message = "cannot be empty")
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
private String isdnNo;
```

This works as expected and I have to provide isdnNo while i do a post request.
And when I get it don't bring the isdnNo in reponse which is fine.
Issue here is in JUnit test case. I am using stand alone setup to test controller.

```
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(bookController).build();
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder postRequest = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/books/").contentType(JSON)
            .accept(JSON);
    postRequest.content(asJsonString(bookDto));
    ResultActions result = mvc.perform(postRequest);
```

This JUnit test case gives exception `org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException` and says idnNo cannot be empty even though I have provided isdnNo in bookDto on performing post. What can be the issue here.

if I remove `@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)` the test case works fine.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep `Access.WRITE_ONLY` removed because, according to the documentation, during serialization (ie writing it to a string) it will not read the value for serialization. You're method asJsonString is serializing the object thus removing the value.

> **AUTO:**
>  Access setting which means that visibility rules are to be used to automatically determine read- and/or write-access of this property.
>   
>   **READ_ONLY:**
>   Access setting that means that the property may only be read for serialization, but not written (set) during deserialization.
>   
> **READ_WRITE**
>   Access setting that means that the property will be accessed for both serialization (writing out values as external representation) and deserialization (reading values from external representation), regardless of visibility rules.
>   
> **WRITE_ONLY**
>   Access setting that means that the property may only be written (set) for deserialization, but will not be read (get) on serialization, that is, the value of the property is not included in serialization.

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html

Comment: when request comes I want to have property but not on response. This works fine with write_only i verified it with postman

Comment: That is correct it will deserialize the object fine back to the class but when you serialize the object again that value will be gone. It might be easier to remove the `write_only` then in actual application null out the fields you don't want returned;

Comment: you are correct @locus2K the issue is when i do `asJsonString(bookDto)` it serializes the object to json and the field is missing. Thanks for help